# scrapy: xpath not returning the full url for @href

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

performing a scrape using xpath with scrapy i dont get the full URL

here is the url i am looking at

using scrapy shell

```
scrapy shell "http://www.ybracing.com/omp-ia01854-omp-first-evo-race-suit.html"
```

i perform the following xpath select from the shell

```
sel.xpath("//*[@id='Thumbnail-Image-Container']/li[1]/a//@href")
```

and get only half the href

```
[<Selector xpath="//*[@id='Thumbnail-Image-Container']/li[1]/a//@href" data=u'http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/160/'>]
```

here's the snippet of html i am looking at in a browser

```
        <li><a data-medimg="http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/160/260/1/medIA01854-GALLERY.jpg" href="http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/160/260/1/lrgIA01854-GALLERY.jpg" class="cloud-zoom-gallery Selected" title="OMP FIRST EVO RACE SUIT" rel="useZoom: 'MainIMGLink', smallImage: 'http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/160/260/1/lrgIA01854-GALLERY.jpg'"><img src="http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/160/260/1/smIA01854-GALLERY.jpg" alt="OMP FIRST EVO RACE SUIT Thumbnail 1"></a></li>
```

and here it is from wget

```
<li><a data-medimg="http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/513/0/medIA01838_GALLERY.JPG" href="http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/513/0/lrgIA01838_GALLERY.JPG" class="cloud-zoom-gallery Selected" title="OMP DYNAMO RACE SUIT" rel="useZoom: 'MainIMGLink', smallImage: 'http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/513/0/lrgIA01838_GALLERY.JPG'"><img src="http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/513/0/smIA01838_GALLERY.JPG" alt="OMP DYNAMO RACE SUIT Thumbnail 1" /></a></li>
```

i have tried varying my xpath to pull the same but still get the same result

what is causing this and what can i do to work around it would like to understand rather than someone just correct my xpath for me

some thoughts on the page itself i disabled javascript to see if the js was generating half the url but its not. I also downloaded the page with wget to confirm the urls are complete in the orriginal html

i havent tested any other builds but i'm using scrapy 1.2.1 on with 2.7  in centos 7

I've googled and only find people who cant grab the data due to javascript generating the data on the fly but my data is there in the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using

```
sel.xpath("//*[@id='Thumbnail-Image-Container']/li[1]/a//@href")
```

you get a list of `Selector` instances, in which the `data` field shows only the first few bytes of all its content (since it might be very long).

To retrieve the content as a string (instead of a `Selector` instance), you would need to use something like `.extract` or `.extract_first`:

```
>>> print(sel.xpath("//*[@id='Thumbnail-Image-Container']/li[1]/a//@href").extract_first())
http://images.esellerpro.com/2489/I/160/260/1/lrgIA01854-GALLERY.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks that explains it perfectly